# given a closed $1$-form $\alpha$, find $0$-form $f$ s.t. $df = \alpha$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, de-rham-cohomology

> Let $\alpha$ be a closed $1$-form on a connected manifold $M$. We
> assume that $M$ is simply connected, i.e. for all paths
> $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ with the same endpoints there exists a smooth
> homotopy $h\colon[0,1]\times[0,1]\to M$ between $\gamma_0$ and
> $\gamma_1$. Use the Poincare-Lemma to show that
>
> $$\int_{\gamma_0}\alpha = \int_0^1\gamma_0^*\alpha = 
> \int_0^1\gamma_1^*\alpha = \int_{\gamma_1}\alpha$$
> Use this
> observation to construct a smooth function $f$ so that $df =  \alpha$.

I struggle to construct the desired function $f$.

So we are obviously looking for a $0$-form $f \in \Omega^0 M$ as the antiderivative $f = \int \alpha$ of our given $\alpha \in \Omega^1M$.

Since $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ are homotopic, it does not depend over which $\gamma_t$ we integrate. Thus $$f = \int_{\gamma_1}\alpha = \int_0^1 \gamma^*\alpha$$

But how do i continue? I know the definition of the pullback of a differential form on a smooth manifold, but i do not know how to make use of it in this case.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance for any advise!

**Addendum:**

For example, the solution to the problem starts with:

> pick $\gamma_i(t)=tx^i$ in coordinates $x^i$

and then proceeds with

> $ f = \int_\gamma \alpha = \int \alpha_{\gamma(t)}\frac{d\gamma}{dt}dt$

but i don't understand what's going on. I don't understand the coordinate-change nor the last integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a point $x_0\in M$, and then for a given point $x\in M$, define
$$f(x):=\int_\gamma \alpha$$
where $\gamma$ is any path from $x_0$ to $x$.

Comment: hello @Berci, thanks for the help. I was hoping to be somehow able to construct something more explicit. For example, the solution to the problem starts with: pick $\gamma^i(t) = tx^i$ in coordinates $x^i$ and then proceeds with $$f = \int_\gamma \alpha = \int_{[0,1]}\alpha_{\gamma(t)}\frac{d\gamma}{dt}dt$$ but i don't understand what's going on. I don't understand the coordinate-change nor the last integral.

Comment: Well, this answer seems explicit to me. You just need to show that it indeed defines a function (that is its independant of the choice of $\gamma$), such that its differential is $\alpha$.

Comment: @DIdier_ It seems like we are assuming that for all $x,y\in M$, there is a path from $x$ to $y$. Is this the definition of "M is connected"?

Comment: @Filippo It is not a definition but an easy result: a connected manifold is path connected (and even smoothly path-connected)

Comment: @DIdier_ Okay, thank you very much!